# Adding image to a pdf is not working as intended

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I'm trying to add an image to a pdf in a specific position, the image is added in the right place however the rest of the content of the pdf disappears. So, I basically get a white pdf with the image in the position that I want. Here's the code:

```java
private void pdf(String mpath) throws DocumentException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();

    String directoryPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download";

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(directoryPath+"/Aa.pdf"));

    document.open();

    Image image = Image.getInstance(mpath);
    image.scalePercent(50);
    image.setAlignment(Image.TEXTWRAP);
    image.scaleAbsolute(200f, 50f);
    image.setAbsolutePosition(200, 300);
    document.add(image);
    document.close();

}
```

Comment: Hi, can you attach the original PDF and image you are trying to add to reproduce the problem? Also, have you tried iText 7? iText 5 is no longer maintained except for security fixes

Comment: Pedro, your file name merely is used to initialize a `FileOutputStream`. Thus, you don't add the image to the existing pdf, you add it to a new pdf that replaces the existing one.